# Sql Query to import data from Excel to table

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Im working with Sql server 2012 and want to import the data from excel to temporary table using sql query.I have the below sample data in excel

### Reason Id Version

t1     1     0                                                                 t2     2     2                                                                t3     3     1

and i want to insert this data from excel sheet to a temporary table.How to write a query for this without using openrowset.

Comment: I recommend you to improve display format of your sample data. Currently it's not really usable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557148/sql-server-how-to-import-excel-to-create-a-table/

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Data Source=C:\excel-sql-server.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0')...[Sheet1$]
```

Please refer the link below, hope it answers your query.

http://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-import-to-sql-server-using-distributed-queries.htm

Comment: I want the query to incorporate data in query itself to not depend on any external file